# Cubic Root verification

Tags: roots, cubics

I'm working on a cubic root question and goes like this...

Let, r,s, and t be the roots of the equation $x^3+ax^2+bx+c = 0$. Re-write the expressions in terms of a,b, and c.

I'm given $r^2+s^2+t^2$. I know that, given 3 roots, I can factor the cubic equation as $(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)$, but don't know what to replace $x$ by in order to get $r^2+s^2+t^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(r+s+t)^2=?$$

Now by Veita's formula $$r+s+t=-\dfrac a1$$ and $$rs+st+tr=\dfrac b1$$

Comment: We haven't studied Vieta's formula in my class just yet. But since we're eventually going to talk about it, in next week's class, I can apply it here then.

Comment: Just because, from what I read, is $rst = -\frac{c}{1}$?

Comment: @jsmith300, Right you are.Why don't read the formula itself?

Comment: Well I'm looking through my textbook, but cannot find it. I'll search it up on this website or Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

> We haven't studied Vieta's formula in my class just yet.

Pretending to not know Vieta's formulas, note that if:

$$P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c = (x-r)(x-s)(x-t)$$

then:

$$P(-x)=-x^3+ax^2-bx+c = -(x+r)(x+s)(x+t)$$

It follows that:

$$
\begin{align}
P(x)P(-x) & = (x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(-x^3+ax^2-bx+c) \\
 & = (ax^2+c)^2-(x^3+bx)^2 \\
 & = -x^6 +x^4(a^2-2b)+\cdots
\end{align}
$$

and also:

$$
\begin{align}
P(x)P(-x) & = -(x^2-r^2)(x^2-s^2)(x^2-t^2) \\
 & =-x^6+x^4(r^2+s^2+t^2)+\cdots
\end{align}
$$

Now equate the coefficient of $x^4$ between the two expressions.

Comment: I would have thought it would be easier to expand $(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)$ and then compare the coefficients. (I know it's technically using Veita's formula, but it's quite easy to derive).

Comment: @mrnovice True, but that's essentially deriving Vieta's formulas for the original polynomial, and that approach was pretty much covered already in the other answer.